# Different outputs when running the same query with different tables names

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following SQL query that runs on snowflake database:

```
select distinct 
  e.website as Website,
  listagg(e.status, ',') as Status,
  e.employee as Employee
from company e
group by
     e.website
     e.employee
```

I'm renaming the table name and the amount of rows returned is different

```
select distinct 
  COM.website as Website,
  listagg(COM.status, ',') as Status,
  COM.employee as Employee
from company as COM
group by
     COM.website
     COM.employee
```

Whenever I change the table name, it returns a result with different amount

You have any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Please also include sample data as it would be helpful for someone looking to test your query to have that.

Comment: Please run both queries with a fully qualified table name (database, schema, table) and see what the counts are

Comment: Are you sure the underlying table is not changing in the meantime? Please add more details so we can reproduce. Also the `group by` doesn't work - where is the comma?

Answer (score 1):

The question is vague, but let's try to investigate it:

a) `DISTINT` is not required when the same non-aggregated columns exist in `GROUP BY`

b) lack of comma on `GROUP BY` clause

c) the only difference that is possible is different order of `LISTAGG` as there is no `WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ...)` - this could lead to different order comma separated string.

To sum up:

```
USE <db.name>.<schema_name>;  -- setting up the same context

SELECT
  e.website AS Website,
  LISTAGG(e.status, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY e.Status) AS Status,
  e.employee AS Employee
FROM company AS e
GROUP BY e.website,
         e.employee;
```

should return the same output regardless of the table alias(as long as underlying table does not change and we are in the context of the same database/schema).